# Algebraic $K$-theory of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

The Quillen's proof of finite generation of algebraic $K$-groups of curves over finite fields has always been a mystery to me. I never understood why working with the Harder-Narasimhan filtration in the proof is natural, it seemed to me like a random idea that happens to work, but I doubt it is random! Is there a good explanation why relating the Harder-Narasimhan filtration to the Tits building of the vector space related to the vector bundles by pulling-back to the generic point is a good idea?

I rationalized this idea maybe something similar to an ad-hoc Devissage theorem. Since each vector bundle admits a filtration that graded pieces are semi-stable maybe this proof is trying to to express algebraic $K$-group in terms of semi-stable bundles. The conditions of the traditional Devissage theorem is not true here. But for example slope zero semi-stable vector bundles form an Abelian category and my guess was that maybe algebraic $K$-theory of this Abelian category together with shifts by tensoring with $\mathcal{O}(1)$ generates the algebraic $K$-groups. Although I can verify this for $\mathbb{P}^1$ but I have no idea whether something like this can be true.

Comment: Is this the correct reference for the argument you are referring to? And is there a freely available version somewhere? https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0062167

Comment: I find a free version here. https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~dan/Papers/FiniteGeneration.pdf

Comment: @user12776 Thanks! I'd never seen or heard about this document before. I don't really have anything terribly useful to say, but maybe it's worth commenting that the Harder-Narasimhan filtration is quite a lot like a composition series for a module, and so it's really a pretty natural thing to consider when looking at algebraic vector bundles. I do wonder what a modern proof of this result would look like, e.g. can modern devissage results (I'm thinking of Barwick's work) be used to give a cleaner proof?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm more interested in the fact the algebraic $K$-group for smooth curves over finite fields are torsion. This result has at least two different proofs first one due to Harder, the second one is in the $K$-book but it uses few big theorems. Both of them rely on this result of Quillen. My guess is that there is some sort of devissage that let's us to represent the $K$-group in terms of the semi-stable bundles. If true I can prove the $K$-groups are going to be torsion, using a trick due to James McKernan.